# How to redirect to a page without using stack navigator in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Is there any way to create a sample login page and a home page in React native without using stack Navigator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**. You can create your own navigation. Even `react-navigation` is a library built by components. If you are building your own navigation it will take more time and effort.

There are several navigation solutions are available for `react-native`. You should use one of this unless it is not fitting your need.

Some of the popular navigation solutions,

[ReactNavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) - Js implementation

[ReactNativeNavigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) - Native implementation

[React Native Router](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) - Js implementation

An advantage of using navigation solutions out there is they got 100s of contributors. The solution is made by more than one person. **Unity is strength**. These libraries are updated frequently by adding more features and fixing bugs.

Using one of these solutions(libs) is a wise choice up to me.

Still, you wanna *build your own navigation*. Please follow [Build Your Own Navigation](https://medium.com/@RanGreenberg/build-your-own-navigation-4492af0c3d6)